# Choose: Six years (seems, seem) too much time to build a house

Tags: word-choice, grammatical-number, verb-agreement

> Choose: **Six years** (seems, seem) too much time to build a house.

I have this question while solving an exam in English, it appears to be "seems" but the plural noun phrase (*six years*) leading you to "seem".

Comment: The sense of the sentence is that (a period of six years) seems too much time. It is not referring to each year individually.

Comment: Mari-Lou A thank you, I've repaired it.

Comment: Kate Bunting, thank you for your answer.